# Why does git status report that a file was deleted after being added with a different worktree?

Tags: git

I'm confused about the output of git status after doing the following. First I initialize a repo in some folder with `git init`. Then I add a file in the parent directory. Then I add the file in the parent directory with `git --work-tree=<parent_direcotory> add <parent_directory/new_file>`. Now under "Changes to be committed", `git status` shows `new file: <new_file>`, as expected. But, under "Changes not staged for commit", it also shows `deleted: <new_file>`. Why does it say that the new file has been deleted? The message persists after committing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does show a deletion, because the work tree by default is "some folder", where you have created the repo.

```
cd /path/to/some/folder
git --work-tree=.. add ../newFile
git status
```

A `git --work-tree=.. status` would show the file, without any deletion.

A `cp ../newFile .` would allow a `git status` (done in the repo folder) to show that file without deletion.

But a `git status` after your `git add` displays a deletion because:

- the index is updated with that file
- the working tree does not include the file (which is still in the parent folder)